# Is there any best way to deploy custom profiles in Salesforce?

Tags: custom-profile

Only user permissions are going if we are migrating the custom profile from one sandbox to other sandbox.

Comment: You have to choose additional metadata if you want permissions to copy as well. For example, if you choose all Apex Classes, those permissions will also copy.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to upload a change set containing only profiles so you'll need to make sure that a component is also included. Profiles are not officially supported as individual components in change sets as [per the Components Available in Change Sets](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=changesets_about_components.htm&type=0) documentation. Although profiles are available and can be selected with other components, there are limitations on what specific parts of the profile's permissions can be deployed via change sets.

Adding profiles or permission sets to outbound change sets is designed to allow administrators to migrate permissions for users so they can access new functionality.  Including profiles in change sets is NOT designed to be a tool or method to update profile settings and permissions for functionality already existing in the target environment as per the [Change Sets Best Practices](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=changesets_best_practices.htm&type=0) documentation.

Starting in API version 30.0, when deploying a new custom field, the default values for the editable and readable fields in profile field permissions are false. To override the default values, include field permissions for the new field in your profiles.

A deployment containing a profile and record type, but not the assigned page layout for that record type, removes the existing layout assignment from the profile for that record type. Always include all page layouts for all required record types in the change set. See the S[pecial Behavior in Deployments](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=deploy_special_behavior.htm&type=0) documentation for more details.

So if you deploy profile keeping everything in mind, you have to check all the permission manually.